# how to end reading by Scanner

Tags: java

I want to read all test cases in UVA Online Judge problem. Test cases are divided by a blank line. Example:
11
20
1
2
3
6
8
12
13
13
15
16
17
18
19
20
20
21
25
26
30
31

12
20
1
2
3
6
8
12
13
13
15
16
17
18
19
20
20
21
25
26
30
31

17
20
1
2
3
6
8
12
13
13
15
16
17
18
19
20
20
21
25
26
30
31

```
while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        numberOfYears = sc.nextInt();
        numberOfPopes = sc.nextInt();

        years = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPopes; i++)
        {
           years.add(sc.nextInt());
        }

        p = new ProblemPope(numberOfYears, numberOfPopes, years);

    }
```

I know, that scanner waits for another line or wants CTRL+Z or CTRL+D. I just want to know if there is a way how to end it after reading all test cases.
Is there a way to do it by Scanner?

Comment: Look for [hasNext()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) methods Or you could use a BufferedReader instead.

Comment: I tried hasNextInt(), it waits too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reading input till EOF in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927326/reading-input-till-eof-in-java)

Comment: have you tried submitting your code?...It works fine when data is taken from file, so it should work for online contests also even if it doesnt work on your IDE.

Comment: I've tried. It ends on runtime error, because it stays in while loop(waits for another line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
while (true) {

    if(!sc.hasNext())
        break;

    ...
}
```

or simply:

```
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It waits for input too. Same as hasNextLine and hasNextInt.

Comment: nope, I just tried to paste it to my code and run it. To console I paste test cases that I wrote above and it runs still

Comment: Thanks a lot, it doesnt work on my pc but it does on their validator.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sc.close()` to close the scanner from reading input

Comment: Well I dont know number of test cases so I dont know when to close it

Comment: it seems like all the cases are ending in 31, so add a check in your if loop: `if (i ==31){ sc.close()}`

Answer (score 0):

Your code might end in runtime error if you do not check hasNext(),hasNextLine() or hasnextInt() getting all inputs.

**But**
Normally the first most input will be the number of testcases in most of the online contests. so you can use it to your advantage like the following.

```
 int testCaseCount= sc.nextInt();
 for(int testCase=0; testcase < testCaseCount; testCase++){
        numberOfYears = sc.nextInt();
        numberOfPopes = sc.nextInt();
    years = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPopes; i++)
    {
       years.add(sc.nextInt());
    }

    p = new ProblemPope(numberOfYears, numberOfPopes, years);
}
```

But if the input does not specify number of test cases, then it is not dynamically entered.

ie it is tested from a file. In such cases the sc.hasNextLine() should work.

if both are not working, please mention the link to the question, so that i can verify what the problem is.

Comment: Usually you know number of test cases, but not this time. It is not from file even.   https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=898

Comment: then try sc.hasNext() instead of sc.hasNextLine(), i have faced such issues once in awhile.