# Exit Java program when user sends EOF (either Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z)

Tags: java, linux

I want to read radiuses in a loop and exit the program when user sends an `EOF` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>).

I'm not familiar with Linux and this combination.

Can anyone please explain what an EOF and these commands do? And how should I implement them?

Comment: You want to read them how? `read()`? `readLine()`? `Scanner`?

Comment: You can try to look at this [reading input till EOF in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927326/reading-input-till-eof-in-java) on how to implement it.

Answer (score -1):

From you program's perspective an EOF is an event when you call a `read` system call, usually performed by a library, which returns less bytes than requested. There is nothing special about it. It's the same when reading lines from STDIN or a file. No more lines, you exit your main loop.

Linux VTE (virtual terminal) devices arrange this for your program when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.

How to do this in Java, I ain't no clue. I can't even read Java. I never find the needle of meaning in the haystack of boilerplate. :)

Comment: Returning less bytes than expected isn't an EOF, it is a short read. Returning an EOF *sentinel* value is EOF, for example `read()` returning -1 in Java.

Comment: I'm referring to the read system call on Linux.  Please read its man page `man 2 read`, then come back and explain me how it returns an EOF. I'm very curious.